What does the hypothesis "EPR=ER" claim?
What does the hypothesis EPR=ER claim? I really do not understand it. Does it claim that if you observe something, a wormhole is being created between you and the observed object?

ER=EPR is the claim (unless I haven’t understood it correctly this whole time) that two entangled particles, e.g. those for which the Einstein-Podolsky-Rosen paradox comes into play (EPR), are connected at the quantum level by an Einstein-Rosen bridge-style wormhole (ER). Originally it was formulated to resolve the EPR “paradox” that is really just an observation of the weirdness of quantum mechanics.
I don’t know how it would be correct, given the difficulty of constructing wormholes - massive negative and positive energy densities that would affect things around it, extremely intense spacetime curvature that would certainly be detectable with an interferometer near entangled particles (I wonder if anyone’s run that experiment), and such - but it allows for a mechanism by which the collapse of one entangled particle’s wave function can instantaneously affect the other regardless of distance.
Very conveniently, the wormhole, being a product of the entanglement, would have to exist as long as the entanglement does but would collapse as soon as you try to observe it. Whether such a quantum wormhole could exist depends on quantum gravity that I won’t try to claim to have a valid theory of.

Would not wormholes allow to transfer signals while quantum entanglement does not?

That is, well, an issue with the idea. You could always say that the wormholes’ collapse blocks information transfer: they’re just a thread that, when the corresponding particle is observed, snaps and changes the other particle. I don’t think the idea has much traction these days anyway.

The ER=EPR claim is explained in Section 1 of this paper:
https://arxiv.org/abs/1604.02589
There are two versions of ER=EPR. One version claims that two black holes connected by an Einstein-Rosen bridge (a wormhole) are entangled. The other version states that entangled particles are connected by an ER bridge.
Both claims depend on the as yet undiscovered theory of quantum gravity and so are difficult to assess since all proposals for such theories are currently untestable.
There is an existing explanation of how Bell correlations and other entanglement phenomena arise in terms of locally inaccessible information carried in decoherent systems:
https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9906007
This has the notable advantage of not requiring any new physics.
